# how to reset opengl modelview matrix?

Tags: opengl-es, matrix

Although I am using opengl es 1.1,but I want to try to work with my own matrix stuff,
I built a fps camera matrix function called : fpsmatrixupdate();
then  I call it like this:

```
fpsmatrixupdate(); //this function generated a matrix called mat
drawbox(min,max)
```

everything works great,until I am trying to draw another box:

```
fpsmatrixupdate(); //this function generated a matrix called mat
drawbox(min,max);
glLoadIdentity();  // I tried to call this before drawbox2 but box2 doesn't show
drawbox2(min,max);
```

questions: why this works?

```
fpsmatrixupdate(); //this function generated a matrix called mat
drawbox(min,max);
glLoadMatrixf(mat);  // mat is fps camera update function generated matrix,
drawbox2(min,max);
```

if I want to draw 200 boxes with different location, do I have to call glLoadMatrixf(mat) 200 times? if I don't call glLoadMatrixf(mat) to reset matrix ,the second box's transform is based on first box..

if anybody want to see the code, they are  almost  99% copied from  this demo:
http://www.codesampler.com/oglsrc/oglsrc_5.htm#ogl_fps_controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want to base your objects' placement on a per-object transformation, you've to do a glLoadMatrix each time. It makes sense to calculate the transformation matrices once and store them in each object's scene data for easy access.